# How to get starting date and final date in a Week based on week number using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I need help to getting fist data and final data from the weeek
For the example:

Now we are in 3/16/2016 and is week 11, and i need to get data1 for Monday: 3/14/2016 and the final data2 for Sunday: 3/20/2016

We know what week is it and i need to know data for Monday and data for sunday.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Define week of year.  Are you using the standard calendar or ISO8601 calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property `DayOfWeek`:

```
    Dim currentTime = New Date(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day)
    Dim startOfWeek = currentTime.AddDays(-currentTime.DayOfWeek)
    Dim endOfWeek = startOfWeek.AddDays(7)
    Dim result = String.Format("Today: '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' / Start of week: '{1:yyyy-MM-dd}' / End of week '{2:yyyy-MM-dd}'", currentTime, startOfWeek, endOfWeek)
    ' result = "Today: '2016-03-16' / Start of week: '2016-03-13' / End of week '2016-03-20'"
```

(Notice that `currentTime` is created this way in order to have all hours/minutes/secons/millisecons set to zero)

...so if your only input is the week number, in this case you will easily get to your desired `currentTime` with this simple transformation:

```
    Dim numberOfWeeks = 11
    Dim startOfYear = New Date(Now.Year, 1, 1)
    Dim currentTime = startOfYear.AddDays(7 * numberOfWeeks)
```